# 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'get_server_version'

Tags: django, django-syncdb, syncdb

I have been using django-1.4.1. And I updated to django1.5.

I inputted '`manage.py sql myapp`' or '`manage.py syncdb`'

then, i got this error "`'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'get_server_version'`"

do you know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to reinstall django. Seems like you've installed django 1.5 on top of django 1.4 and this causes an error.